# How can I turn sharing and Windows Defender on/off from the Windows 8 command line?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, command-line

Whenever I connect to public wifi, I turn sharing off and turn Windows Defender on and switch sharing back on when I disconnect (Windows Defender never seems to stay on anyway). I'd like to have 2 files on my desktop that I can just run before and after to save myself some time. Can anyone tell me how to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: Just leave Windows Defender always on (why would you disable it in the first place?) and set up Windows to use sharing only on home networks. Windows asks you if the network is public when you connect to it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to change anything about Windows Defender. It is a service named "WinDefend" which you can not stop as an administrator or even as the local system account.

In the registry there is a value:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection\DisableRealtimeMonitoring
```

but you can not change it as a normal administrator either.

You may be able to run a command under the local system account to change the value, but Defender may not pick that up anyways.

There is a command line interface to Defender:

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe
```

but it doesn't have any options to stop the real-time protection.

So I guess you are out of luck.